# How can my rails server call an ngrok instance without me knowing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Somehow both my dev(local) and production(hosted on Heroku) Rails app, called `import`, is calling a script on an unrelated `ngrok` server. I call `sync`

And I have no idea how.

All I get is this error:

`Cannot GET /packs/js/sync-74d9cc2fb37b2c8f654b.js`

Which I also cannot find, but I can turn on the `sync` ngrok server and see the request come through via from `import`

I started with my `public/packs` folder in `import` and did a `bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber`  to get rid of all the old `packs` in `public/packs` but this didn't help.

I've searched my code and github for `ngrok` and `sync` and no luck..

Here is my js file in `javascript/packs`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../app.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { routes } from '../router/routes'
import store  from '../store/store'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import lodash from 'lodash'
import qs from 'qs'
import createApp from '@shopify/app-bridge/development'
import { Redirect } from '@shopify/app-bridge/actions';
import VueTheMask from 'vue-the-mask'
import CountryFlag from 'vue-country-flag'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
import { getSessionToken } from "@shopify/app-bridge-utils"
import { respond } from '@shopify/app-bridge/actions/AuthCode'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueLodash,{lodash: lodash})
Vue.use(VueTheMask)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
Vue.component('country-flag', CountryFlag)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    } else {
      return { top: 0 }
    }
  }
});

function getSession(app) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window['app-bridge-utils'].getSessionToken(app).then(token => {
      resolve(token);
    });
  })
}

var data = ''
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  data = document.getElementById('shopify-app-init').dataset;
  var AppBridge = window['app-bridge'];
  let createAppValue = createApp({
    apiKey: data.apiKey,
    shopOrigin: data.shopOrigin,
    host: data.host
  });
  const app = new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount()
  document.body.appendChild(app.$el);
  let sessionResponse = await getSession(createAppValue)
  app.$options.store.commit('token/changeToken', sessionResponse)
  app.$options.store.commit('shop/changeShop', data.shopOrigin)
})

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.paramsSerializer = params => {
    return qs.stringify(params, {
      arrayFormat: "brackets",
      encode: false
    });
  };
  return config
})
```

And then as its happening in both production and dev, here is my `application.rb` file

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Bytestand20
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.1

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")
  end
end
```

I've searched my `import` code for anything with `sync` in it, and no luck. My `ENV` variables in both prod and dev have nothing with `sync` even in it..

I'm stuck and not even sure where to start. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You might have a gem that has that asset within it. Maybe check your gemfile and the corresponding code to see if something from there is bringing it in?